# How to use kaobook template with greek language and XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, greek, kaobook

**TL;DR**

***How can I compile kaobook template with greek language using XeLaTeX?***

I have been trying to compile [kaobook](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/kaobook) with XeLaTeX for a book in greek language without success.
The template uses polyglossia package. When changing the language to greek with `\setmainlanguage{greek}` it doesn't compile returning a misleading error about the fonts that turned out to be irrelevant. After setting the fonts explicitly it return an other error. Finaly I figured out that there was a problem with the kaorefs.sty and the definitions there but I could not go further.